# How to Add Description to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I would like to add an explanation to each chapter... like the picture...

[image]

Is there a way to edit the TOC in this way??

I need to have a similar result to the one shown in the picture above.

Comment: Alright, do you suggest me to create another question?

Comment: Yes, that would be better, you can link to this question of course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that the descriptions should not be used with page numbers as well, so I provide a macro named `\desctotoc` which writes the argument to the ToC and leaves some medium vertical space afterwards.

In order to prevent fragile commands causing errors, I used a `\detokenize` - approach within `\addtocontents` which is the 'master' macro for writing contents to a ToC - related file.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\desctotoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\medskip\noindent\detokenize{#1}\leavevmode\par\medskip}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\desctotoc{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{itemize}
}

\chapter{Foobar}

\desctotoc{\blindtext}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Would it be possible to include any description AND page number?

Anyway helped lots. 
thanks

Comment: @Adriano - Do you know about the `\pageref` command to generate call-outs to page numbers?

Comment: @Mico Went looking for some help about the `\pageref`, but I do not know how to include the page number in its aproppriate place.